# specific div css properties

Tags: html, css, ftp

I have a div : `<div id="fancyboxID-1">
        <p>0767380042</p>
        </div>`
and this css:

`​ #fancyboxID-1 p { font-size:150px; text-align: center; line-height:150px; overflow:hidden;}`

After I upload and refresh the website I don't see any changes but if I check the source code: I see the css properties.

It's very strange for me, I've tried to upload on another server and there it works.
Any ideas why this is not working ?

Comment: Caching is ruled out as you mentioned you see the CSS changes in the source code. It could be that the properties are getting overridden, did you try to inspect the element in question to inspect the properties ?

Comment: I've tried and I don't see any proprietes related to that div in Chrome console for example

Comment: Have you tried another browser? Have you _explicitly_ cleared the cache? Is there more HTML/CSS than this?

Comment: I've cleared the cache, tried another browser and the same, it seems that is overriden by `p` css proprietes when I inspect element instead of showing `#fancyboxID-1 p` { } is just `p`

Comment: press ctrl+f5 then check may be its cache problem

Comment: Is your CSS in an external file? When it doesn't work - you literally see no style change at all? Is the server returning the correct mime-type for your .css file?

Comment: Yes, css is an external file, I've tried the same files uploaded on another server and is working fine

Comment: So this could be from the server?

Comment: If there is a difference between servers then one server could be returning an incorrect mime-type for your .css file. It should be "text/css". This would prevent the CSS file from being interpreted as CSS and consequently no styles will be applied.

Comment: I have "text/css" , I think the only solution left is to ask the web hosting company  ?

Comment: I suspect that if your CSS files are indeed returning the correct HTTP response then your hosting company is going to say that it's a client-side issue (ie. "your problem").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your stylesheet (style.css) there appears to be some strange characters (corruption / unicode?) before your problematic line which is probably invalidating your stylesheet. Removing these characters results in your styles suddenly bursting to life...

When viewed with ISO-8859-1 encoding, they appear as 4 visible characters, although if viewed as UTF-8 it just looks like a single space (although it's not a single space):

```
â€‹ #fancyboxID-1 p { font-size:150px; ...
```

(Btw, hyphens in the id/class names are perfectly valid.)

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other styles\sheets that are overriding these changes?  You said it works on other servers, so there must be something specific to the server youre hosting from.

If you use developer tools (F12 in IE or Chrome, Firebug in FireFox) you can browse to see if the changes are actually applied.. the code being present only means those styles are available, but something else might be enforcing different rules against that div, p, etc.

Comment: When I look in console the matched css rules are for `p` not for `#fancyboxID-1 p`

Comment: Can you share the URL?  If not, have you had other internal\external users try?

Comment: Oh, and try getting rid of the dash in the name, just bc some characters cause weird stuff.  Seems to me that your id isn't matching up from your styles.

Comment: [here](http://ibizapartypeople.com) is the link click on the first icon on the footer (right)